# How to clear html form via php?

Tags: php, html

I want to clear my form with the help of PHP after submitting the form and updating the record.

Comment: What do you mean "clear my form"?  Can you explain your problem in more detail, please?  How about some code demonstrating the issue?

Comment: Huh? Quite the opposite, you usually need to produce a lot of code to *persist* form input. Clearing it should be as simple as doing nothing...

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to redirect the user after submit a form. this will clear all POST or GET data.

```
header('Location: foobar.php');
```

or you can unset the values after a successful submit.

```
unset($_POST['fieldname'], $_POST['fieldname2']);
```

Comment: Clearing POST variables won't help anything as far as I know. If the user reloads the page, the POST data will be resent.

Answer (score 1):

Just unset the variables that you use to populate your form.

Answer (score 0):

**a html form is client side... and PHP runs server side**, essentially you are going to have to reset the values of the form using a client side code, on the onsubmit action. The simplest way to do this would be to use javascript to clear the values of all the inputs.

Comment: The *simplest* way for client-side reset is `<input type="reset" "reset the form." />` but I'm not convinced that's the question being asked.

Comment: this is a correct answer, but I also think it's a good practice to have a backup in case let's say, javascript is not enabled (rare but could happen). So if you don't do this via php and javascript is not enable, your site won't be functional. Or at least a big part of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can `unset POST/GET` variables and avoid data resend if the page is reloaded:

PHP code: (avoidResend.php):

```
if(!empty($_POST) OR !empty($_FILES))
{
    $_SESSION['save'] = $_POST ;
    $_SESSION['saveFILES'] = $_FILES ;

    $currentFile = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ;
    if(!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']))
    {
        $currentFile .= '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ;
    }

    header('Location: ' . $currentFile);
    exit;
}

if(isset($_SESSION['save']))
{
    $_POST = $_SESSION['save'] ;
    $_FILES = $_SESSION['saveFILES'] ;

    unset($_SESSION['save'], $_SESSION['saveFILES']);
}
```

include this file at the very top of your page, and after submitting the form then `unset($_POST['v1'], $_POST['v2'], $_POST['v3']);`

Cheers!